# Remove duplicates from each value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with list of lists that looks like this:

```
{'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']], 'S24': [['2016-03-19', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']], 'S25': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']]}
```

I want to go through each list and remove any duplicate sub_lists. So, for example the key S26 has two duplicates in the lists:

```
'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']]
```

This key should now be:

```
'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']]
```

Is this possible? The python version on this system is 2.6.6

Comment: You mean duplicate sub_lists not items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for val in dict:
    tmp=[]
    for l in dict[val]:
        if l not in tmp: tmp.append(l)
    dict[val]=tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works as well:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> d = {'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']], 'S24': [['2016-03-19', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']], 'S25': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']]}
>>> 
>>> out_d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in d.items():
        for vv in v:
            if vv not in out_d[k]:
                out_d[k].append(vv)

>>> out_d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'S24': [['2016-03-19', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']], 'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']], 'S25': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
d = {'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']], 'S24': [['2016-03-19', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']], 'S25': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']]}

answer = {k:[list(el) for el in set([tuple(sublist) for sublist in v])]
             for k, v in d.items()}
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
{'S24': [['2016-03-19', '2016-03-25'], 
         ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']],
 'S25': [['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'],
         ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'],
         ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']],
 'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']]}
```

This iterates over each `(k, v)` pair of elements in the dictionary and removes the duplicate sublists from the list value. To do this, we use a list comprehension to convert each `sublist` to a `tuple` so that we can create a `set` (since lists aren't hashable).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve the ordering of the lists, the following approach would work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dlol = {
    'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']], 
    'S24': [['2016-03-19', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']], 
    'S25': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']]}

output = {}

for k, lol in dlol.items():
    output[k] = OrderedDict([(tuple(e), None) for e in lol])

output = {k: list(list(e) for e in v) for k, v in output.items()}    
print(output)
```

Giving you:

```
{'S25': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-20', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']], 
'S24': [['2016-03-19', '2016-03-25'], ['2016-03-25', '2016-04-03']], 
'S26': [['2016-03-18', '2016-03-28']]}
```